# How to remove ViewState from updatepanel Ajax requests?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, asp.net-4.0

I am already storing the viewstate in session. However when I use updatepanel, I still see this:

> |0|hiddenField|_*EVENTTARGET||0|hiddenField|*_EVENTARGUMENT||0|hiddenField|_*LASTFOCUS||72|hiddenField|*_VIEWSTATE|/wEPZwUPOGQwMTViZDAyYzljM2RiDkOzqPgrsrLq7oLjMrtEqvksOkereJ+iwT7JWm4o3eY=|1|hiddenField|_*SCROLLPOSITIONX|0|1|hiddenField|*_SCROLLPOSITIONY|0|2524|hiddenField|__EVENTVALIDATION|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|0|asyncPostBackControlIDs|||0|postBackControlIDs|||102|updatePanelIDs||tctl00$Body$updIGrp,,tctl00$Body$updITyp,,tctl00$Body$updRpt,,tctl00$Body$updSrch,,tctl00$Body$updDoc,|0|childUpdatePanelIDs|||57|panelsToRefreshIDs||ctl00$Body$updRpt,,ctl00$Body$updSrch,,ctl00$Body$updDoc,|2|asyncPostBackTimeout||90|0|formAction|||39|scriptStartupBlock|ScriptContentNoTags|removeLastColumn('ctl00_Body_grvDocs');|208|scriptStartupBlock|ScriptContentNoTags|Sys.Application.add_init(function()
>   { $create(Sys.UI._UpdateProgress,
>   {"associatedUpdatePanelId":"ctl00_Body_updRpt","displayAfter":0,"dynamicLayout":false},
>   null, null, $get("ctl00_Body_ctl07"));

Is there any way I can prevent this from being sent in response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extracted from stackoverflow:

> The __VIEWSTATE field is also used to store control state, which is
>   not optional. Furthermore, the information contained in the view state
>   is used to validate the postback, if I'm not mistaken (and validation
>   is enabled, which is the default). So as long as you have the form
>   with runat="server", you'll have a viewstate field. However, you
>   should notice a much smaller field size if you disable all viewstate.

By the way, there are some tricks to remove the viewstate. Check the following post:

[**Override Render and strip ViewState out with a Regex.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432972/completely-remove-viewstate-for-specific-pages)

Answer (score 1):

Set the 'EnableViewState=false' on the UpdatePanel. This will disable the ViewState of all child controls contained within in. Or, if you need a more granular approach, you can disable the ViewState on a control by control basis too.