# How do I not pass the viewstate when posting to an external url from aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm posting data to a 3rd party website via button click on a aspx page with a masterpage.

However when I post my data the __VIEWSTATE variable is being passed along in the post.
I don't wish to remove the Viewstate for the page. I just want to not pass along the __VIEWSTATE  variable in a post.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: http://www.devcurry.com/2011/02/remove-viewstate-from-aspnet-page.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432972/completely-remove-viewstate-for-specific-pages might help you

Answer (score 2):

I've gone with moving the Viewstate to session via pagestatepersister override.

```
/// <summary>
/// Move viewstate to session
/// </summary>
protected override PageStatePersister PageStatePersister
{
    get
    {
        return new SessionPageStatePersister(Page);
    }
}
```

http://brianreiter.org/2010/02/24/override-pagestatepersister-to-eliminate-viewstate/

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe do a reverse proxy which means you post to an internal page that in turn posts to the external page with the parameters you want to include.

Comment: gah. I guess I could post from the codebehind. but I wanted to avoid doing more coding. I guess that's unavoidable.